# How do I replace words with increasing numbers?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

For example, the only thing in file.txt looks like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxHAHAxxxxxxHOHOxxxxxxx
```

I hope to replace HAHA with seq 1 3 and replace HOHO with seq 5 7, so the output should be:

```
xxxxxxxxx1xxxxxx5xxxxxxx   
xxxxxxxxx2xxxxxx6xxxxxxx   
xxxxxxxxx3xxxxxx7xxxxxxx
```

What I did:

```
for i in $(seq 1 3)    
do  sed "s/HAHA/$i/g" file.txt   
  for i in $(seq 5 7)    
  do sed "s/HOHO/$i/g" file.txt   
  done   
done > new.txt
```

But new.txt doesn't show what I expected. How should I change the code?

Comment: By the way, I added four spaces to each line of my code, but it doesn't format like what it should be like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it, using the `bash` built-in `read` command's ability to read from different file descriptors:

```
while read -u3 i && read -u4 j; do 
    sed -e "s/HAHA/$i/" -e "s/HOHO/$j/" file.txt
done > new.txt 3< <(seq 1 3) 4< <(seq 5 7)
```

---

Since your numbers have a simple arithmetic relationship, it would be simpler to use a single `seq` process + some shell arithmetic:

```
for i in $(seq 1 3); do
  sed -e "s/HAHA/$i/" -e "s/HOHO/$((i+4))/" file.txt
done > new.txt
```

In either case, see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) - the inefficiencies may not matter for the minimal example you have provided, but if you are doing anything more serious you should consider using a different approach.

Comment: I wonder why you use 3 and 4 after the -u. Did you just choose these numbers randomly?

Comment: @LittleG they are the first two numbers after the terminal's standard input / output / error streams (fd `0`, `1`, `2`)  that are available as file descriptors

Comment: In the first solution, why do you add a space between the two <?

Comment: @LittleG iirc it's necessary in order for the shell parser to distinguish `< <(command)` from the here-document syntax `<< word`, but I may be wrong about that: see for example [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Comment: I've just seen the link you added. Well, they say it's bad to use a loop to process text, but in this case, we can't avoid the loop.

Comment: @LittleG you may not be able to avoid a loop, but you can avoid a *shell* loop, as shown in [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504221/65304)

Answer (score 2):

Without calling an external utility for each line produced:

```
read template <file

paste <(seq 1 3) <(seq 5 7) |
while read x y; do
    t=${template/HAHA/$x}
    t=${t/HOHO/$y}
    printf '%s\n' "$t"
done >new.txt
```

This first reads the line from the file called `file` into `$template`.  It then constructs a two-column input for a `while read` loop.  The input to the loop is the two columns of numbers from `seq`.

In the loop, some `bash`-specific substitutions are performed on the value of `$template` to replace the `HAHA` and `HOHO` string with the numbers read from `paste`.  This creates `$t` which is then outputted.

---

Using only `awk`, and assuming that the input is a single line only:

```
awk '{
         for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
             t = $0;
             sub("HAHA",   i, t)
             sub("HOHO", 4+i, t)
             print t
         }
     }' file
```

---

A shell loop for `bash`, mimicking the `awk` code above:

```
read template <file

for (( i = 1; i <= 3; ++i )); do
    t=${template/HAHA/$i}
    t=${t/HOHO/$((i+4))}
    printf '%s\n' "$t"
done
```

Comment: You said 'Without calling an external utility' - does this mean it runs faster than calling sed?

Comment: @LittleG Calling an external utility, like `sed`, in a loop is slow in comparison to using only built-in utilities in a loop, yes.